# how to call attributes in the function expression?

Tags: rapidminer

my problem is what i need to write in the function expression in order to represent the prediction(label)?I mean how to call attributes in the function expression? this expression didn't work:

```
parent_path + "/" +"/new/" +prediction_label+ "/" + file_name
```

Comment: This is not a clear question - it should include the names of the example set being used to create the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use square brackets around the names of the attributes and be sure to use the exact names of the attributes. For reference, the `Generate Attributes` operator does a lot of the work for you. If you click on `function descriptions` you will see a small calculator-like icon to the right of function expressions. Once in this, you can select `Special Attributes` and you will see the exact names of the prediction attributes. Double clicking on the special attribute will cause it to be copied into the expression with square brackets if they are needed.

Comment: i guess it don't need brackets around the names of the attributes just type its name? that's what i wached in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6uBKg9-EMRk

Comment: You need square brackets if the name could be misinterpreted as a mathematical operation.

Comment: yes, thankyou, i faced this problem in calling prediction(label) attribute, it missinterrepted as implicit multiplication